# Unable to select iOS simulator via RoboVM IntelliJ IDEA plugin on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, robovm

I'm experiencing an issue where I am unable to select an iOS simulator via RoboVM IntelliJ IDEA plugin on Android Studio.

Under Run/Debug Configurations, when I try to create a new RoboVM iOS configuration and select Simulator type, the Device Type and Architecture dropdown fields are blank.

I am developing an iOS libGDX application using RoboVM. I have RoboVM 2.3.5, RoboVM IntelliJ IDEA plugin 2.3.5 on Android Studio 3.3. I have Xcode 10.2 installed and iOS 12.2 SDK installed. In Xcode I am able to see simulators there so I know that they exist.

I will appreciate any advice on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simctl now returns modified format of simulator data. 
there was a [PR355](https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/pull/355) that fixed the issue and it is merged already to master. 
you have options to build robovm from source, use [user-pre-build one](https://gitter.im/MobiVM/robovm?at=5cb300841f6e900d5e2ec93e), or wait of official snapshot.

Comment: here is official snapshot build [available](http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/downloads/snapshots/idea/)